# The Flagging Screen in Moderation Tools Should be set up like the Approve/Reject Edits Screen

Tags: feature-request, user-interface, 10k-tools

I believe the Flag Summary Screen should be set up similar to the Approve/Reject Edits Screen, such that users can view the question or answer that is being flagged.  This will make it easier to determine what was being flagged as well as limit the number of mistakes being made when flagging an answer or question.  In addition this should make the user experience better instead of clicking the flagged item to view it and back button to go back (less clicks).

What does everyone think?